# insert query not working in golang

Tags: mysql, go

In my golang program, the insert MySQL query was not inserting the values. Even the syntax of the query was correct.It returns my error statement ie internal server error

```
            package main

            import (

            "database/sql"
            "net/http"
             "log"
            "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
            "encoding/json"
            _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
            "fmt"

            )


            const hashCost = 8
            var db *sql.DB


            func initDB(){
                var err error
```

// Connect to the db
//you might have to change the connection string to add your database credentials

```
          db, err = sql.Open("mysql", 
     "root:nfn@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/mydb")

                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }
```

// Create a struct that models the structure of a user, both in the request body, and in the DB

```
                    type Credentials struct {
                    Password string `json:"password", db:"password"`
                      Username string `json:"username", db:"username"`
               }

            func Signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
                // Parse and decode the request body into a new `Credentials` instance
                creds := &Credentials{}
                err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(creds)
                if err != nil {
                    // If there is something wrong with the request body, return a 400 status
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
                    return
                }
                // Salt and hash the password using the bcrypt algorithm
                // The second argument is the cost of hashing, which we arbitrarily set as 8 (this value can be more or less, depending on the computing power you wish to utilize)
                hashedPassword, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(creds.Password), 8)

                // Next, insert the username, along with the hashed password into the database
```

// Sql query not working Here.How to solve this error

```
                        if _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO users(username,password) VALUES (?,?) ", creds.Username, string(hashedPassword)); err != nil {
                    // If there is any issue with inserting into the database, return a 500 error
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                    return
                }
```

// We reach this point if the credentials we correctly stored in the database, and the default status of 200 is sent back
                }

Comment: write your error on header rather than Status code to check what error is returned from the database.

Comment: first log.println(err)...then complain if its empty

Comment: Are you sure you have `autocommit` flag enabled for your DB?

Comment: Have you solved this error? Coz, I too getting this error.